# Removing extra pivot object in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pivot-table

I'm using Laravel 4 and have my pivot tables working and pulling data as expected, but with every relation call, I end up getting an additional `pivot` object returned.

For example:

```
"entities": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NAME",
        "short_name": "SHORT",
        "description": "",
        "pivot": {
            "project_id": 1,
            "entity_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Is there a way to remove the extra pivot object in the call? Below is the current code I have in my Project model.

```
public function entities() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Entity', 'project_entity');
}
```

Comment: Add "pivot" to your `$hidden` property on the Eloquent model; like `protected $hidden = array('pivot');`

Comment: So, easy, but didn't even think of trying that. Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonySterling What if I want to hide only `project_id` from pivot key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was answered by @Anthony Sterling under the comments. I had to add 'pivot' under the protected array in the model.

```
<?php

class Entity extends Eloquent {
    protected $hidden = array('pivot');
    protected $guarded = array();
    protected $fillable = array();
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```